# Как можно реализовать показ текущего выбранного элемента списка в диалоге?

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-dialog

Реализовал диалог с одиночным выбором при помощи фрагментов. Теперь нужно сделать, чтоб ранее выбранный элемент при следующем вызове диалога отображался( checked == true). Что-то сижу и не могу ничего придумать. Был бы очень признателен помощи в данном вопросе, не обязательно с примером кода(хотя это было бы здорово!), а хотя бы просто алгоритм моих действий на словах.

Вот мои наработки.
сам фрагмент диалога:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    private ListView list;
    private DialogListAdapter adapter;

    private String[] data = {"liq", "bin", "nex", "rex", "hex", "stmell"};

    public static MyDialogFragment newInstance() {
        MyDialogFragment f = new MyDialogFragment();
        f.setStyle(1, 0);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toolbar_ts_acc_dialog_layout, null);

        Button btnOk = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_dialog_btn_ok);
        Button btnCancel = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_dialog_btn_cancel);
        list = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_dialog_accout_list);

        adapter = new DialogListAdapter(getActivity(), data);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);

        btnOk.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.toolbar_dialog_btn_ok:
                TextView accName = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar_dialog_show_tv);
                int checked = list.getCheckedItemPosition();
                if (checked >= 0)
                    accName.setText(data[checked]);
                break;
            case R.id.toolbar_dialog_btn_cancel:
                break;
        }
        dismiss();
    }

    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            adapter.setSelectedItem(position);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

и адаптер:

```
public class DialogListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private String[] data;
    private final Context context;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;

    private int selectedItem = -1;

    public DialogListAdapter(Context context, String[] data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toolbar_ts_acc_dialog_list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.radioButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_dialog_radio);
            holder.accName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_dialog_acc_name);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.accName.setText(data[position]);
        if (selectedItem == position) {
            holder.radioButton.setChecked(true);
        } else
            holder.radioButton.setChecked(false);

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView accName;
        public RadioButton radioButton;
    }

    public void setSelectedItem(int num) {
        selectedItem = num;
    }
}
```

Comment: Например сохранить в `SharedPreferences` позицию выбранного, а при создании фрагмента достать и просеттить. Есть и другие варианты - в зависимости от условий при которых позиция должна восстанавливаться или не должна

Comment: а если мне нужно прокинуть сохраненное значение в другой фрагмент? Я смогу достать эти SharedPreferences в другом фрагменте?

Comment: и я не понимаю, где это нужно делать? в адаптере или в фрагменте?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй так. C помощью SharedPreferences сохраняешь выбранную позицию listView вызывая метод savePosition(), и с помощью loadPosition() получаешь. Про метод listview.setselection я не уверен что будет работать, если что смотри [вот сдесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446373/android-listview-setselection-does-not-seem-to-work)

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener{

        private ListView list;
        private DialogListAdapter adapter;

        private String[] data = {"liq", "bin", "nex", "rex", "hex", "stmell"};

        SharedPreferences sPref;

        final String SAVED_POSITION = "saved_position";

        public static MyDialogFragment newInstance() {
            MyDialogFragment f = new MyDialogFragment();
            f.setStyle(1, 0);
            return f;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toolbar_ts_acc_dialog_layout, null);

            Button btnOk = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_dialog_btn_ok);
            Button btnCancel = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_dialog_btn_cancel);
            list = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_dialog_accout_list);

            adapter = new DialogListAdapter(getActivity(), data);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            list.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);

            listView.requestFocusFromTouch();
            listView.setSelection(loadPosition()); 

            btnOk.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnCancel.setOnClickListener(this);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.toolbar_dialog_btn_ok:
                    TextView accName = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar_dialog_show_tv);
                    int checked = list.getCheckedItemPosition();
                    if (checked >= 0)
                        accName.setText(data[checked]);
                    break;
                case R.id.toolbar_dialog_btn_cancel:
                    break;
            }
            dismiss();
        }

        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                savePosition(position);
                adapter.setSelectedItem(position);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
      private void savePosition(int position) {
        sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor ed = sPref.edit();
        ed.putInt(SAVED_POSITION, position);
        ed.commit();
      }

      private int loadPosition() {
        sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sPref.getInt(SAVED_POSITION, 0);

      }
    }
```

Comment: Так и сделал. спасибо!